# Why is the rate of change of area under a curve equal to the height of the curve at the second endpoint?

Tags: calculus

This is the fundamental rule of calculus, and I see the math process and all, but I can't intuitively understand why the statement is true, like why the second endpoint, why doesn't the first matter? How is this intuitive? Any real life examples?

Comment: Does [this diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/FTC_geometric.svg/627px-FTC_geometric.svg.png) from wikipedia help?

Comment: The first endpoint doesn't matter simply because you're taking the derivative with respect to the second endpoint (and assuming the first is constant).

Answer (score 0):

When $x$ changes by $h$,
the area from $x$ to $x+h$
is a rectangle
with sides $h$ and $f(x)$
with a little triangle
(approximately) on top
with an area of
$h(f(x+h)-f(x))/2
=(h^2/2)(f(x_h)-f(x))/h
\approx h^2f'(x)/2
$.

Therefore
the area changes by about
$hf(x)+h^2f'(x)/2$.
Since we consider $h$
to be small,
the $h^2f'(x)/2$ term
is negligible 
compared with the
$hf(x)$ term,
so that is how much
the area changes by
for small $h$.